# EXPLAIN tables with qualifier error while doing SQL tuning in IBM Data Studio

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

when I clicked on start tuning button by selecting my code, IBM data studio gives me error of EXPLAIN tables.

I am using db2 10.1 on windows 10. see below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Then I run this command:

```
CALL SYSPROC.SYSINSTALLOBJECTS('EXPLAIN', 'C', 
CAST (NULL AS VARCHAR(128)), CAST (NULL AS VARCHAR(128)))
```

this command will create all the explain tables in your database.
but again clicking on start tuning button it is giving me this error:

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: See here: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/db2/getting-an-execution-plan

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the *User Response* in the message, and if so, post exactly what messages you receive.

> "In the Configuration Status section of the Advanced Configuration and
>   Privelge Management window, click the Drop button for the EXPLAIN
>   tables.
>
> Then, follow one of these steps:
>
> -- next to the Drop button, click the Create button for the EXPLAIN tables
>
> OR
>
> -- run the EXPLAIN.DDL file that is in the installation directory for your version of Db2-LUW."

If your Db2-server is running on Z/os or iSeries then you need to tell us which, and also the Db2 version.

Comment: It appears that you tried to manually create the explain tables via the sysinstallobjects method instead of following the instructions in the original message.   Suggest you follow the original instructions, including the drop action first.    If your Db2 server is running on Windows and you connect to the database with the db2admin account  then the following the original instructions will drop and recreate the explain tables and they will have the correct permissions.  If you are *not* connecting as db2admin and the tables already exist then you need to give these details.

Comment: which instruction you are talking about, you can edit your answer as well. I called this procedure mentioned in the link of comment.